# Why does my action button in my MUI snackbar take up an extra line?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx, snackbar

I'm new to using MUI and can't figure this one out after digging through the docs. The close button is taking up an extra line when I would like for it to be on the same line as "again". I've tried playing around with absolute positioning but I haven't had any luck.

[image]

```
...const action = (
    <>
      <IconButton
        size="small"
        aria-label="close"
        color="inherit"
        onClick={toggleMessage}
      >
        <CloseIcon fontSize="small" />
      </IconButton>
    </>
  )

  return (
    <>
      {message && (
        <Snackbar
          ContentProps={{
            sx: {
              backgroundColor: 'green',
              borderRadius: 0,
              width: '100vh',
            },
          }}
          anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'center' }}
          message={props.message}
          open={message}
          action={action}
        ></Snackbar>...
```

Comment: Forgot to add, it works fine if the text is just one line but if the text takes up a second line it will push the close icon to a third line.

Comment: You could open inspect and check element to see it more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Snackbar
   // other props
   ContentProps={{
      sx: {
         flexWrap: 'nowrap',       // <--- Add this
         // other styles
         // If you want to handle actions container styles, add this:
         '& .MuiSnackbarContent-action': {
            // Or handle button styles, add this:
                // actions container css
               '& button': {
                  // button css
               }
          }
      },
   }}
   action={action}
>
```